# Statement Invalid in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) gem. It works fine when I open the admin panel from localhost but then I get this error whenever i tried to show the user inside rails admin panel.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RailsAdmin::Main#show

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column relationships.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relations...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."user_id" = $1
```

I realised this error might come from my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
end
```

relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"    
end
```

I don't have any idea at all why at fist the error said the `relationship.user_id` does not exist. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is telling you that the relationships table underneath the Relationship model does not have a `user_id` column.

When you use the `has_many` association in the User model, then you need to have a `user_id` column in the relationships table per: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Examine the relationships table in the database to see the structure of the table.  It would seem you need a migration to add the `user_id` column to that table.

Comment: That's the thing, but it's not really what I want. I don't want to add user_id into `relationship` table since it already have `follower` and `following` which contain the `user_id`s. See the tutorial that I followed for this example code: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users. From what I understand, it supposed have no problem with the user_id.

Comment: What is the line in the code that is raising the error?  Could you please modify the question and add that information?